# Hibernate not returning results for the mappings

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to define the mappings among entities. When I try to use spring data jpa to get users table data by id, I am only able to see the fields defined in users entity, I am not able to get the mapping results. Could someone please suggest what is wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", schema = "public")
public class Users implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_VERIFIED")
    private String emailVerified;

    @Column(name = "MOBILE_VERIFIED")
    private String phoneVerified;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "people")
    @JsonBackReference
    private ProgrammeMemberships programmeMemberships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "peopleTable")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<ContactsNumbers> contactsNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ContactsNumbers> getContactsNumbers() {
        return contactsNumbers;
    }

    public void setContactsNumbers(List<ContactsNumbers> contactsNumbers) {
        this.contactsNumbers = contactsNumbers;
    }

    public Long getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Long personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getEmailVerified() {
        return emailVerified;
    }

    public void setEmailVerified(String emailVerified) {
        this.emailVerified = emailVerified;
    }

    public String getPhoneVerified() {
        return phoneVerified;
    }

    public void setPhoneVerified(String phoneVerified) {
        this.phoneVerified = phoneVerified;
    }

    public ProgrammeMemberships getProgrammeMemberships() {
        return programmeMemberships;
    }

    public void setProgrammeMemberships(ProgrammeMemberships programmeMemberships) {
        this.programmeMemberships = programmeMemberships;
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBERS", schema = "public")
public class Members implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MEM_UID")
    private Long memUid;

    @Column(name = "PTS_BAL")
    private Long ptsBal;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE_STATUS")
    private String activeStatus;

    @Column(name = "CHANGED")
    private Date changed;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PER_PERSON_ID")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private People people;


    public ProgrammeMemberships() {
    }

    public ProgrammeMemberships(Long memUid, Long ptsBal, String activeStatus, Date changed) {
        this.memUid = memUid;
        this.ptsBal = ptsBal;
        this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
        this.changed = changed;
    }


    public Long getMemUid() {
        return memUid;
    }

    public void setMemUid(Long memUid) {
        this.memUid = memUid;
    }

    public Long getPtsBal() {
        return ptsBal;
    }

    public void setPtsBal(Long ptsBal) {
        this.ptsBal = ptsBal;
    }

    public String getActiveStatus() {
        return activeStatus;
    }

    public void setActiveStatus(String activeStatus) {
        this.activeStatus = activeStatus;
    }

   public People getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(People people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    public Date getChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    public void setChanged(Date changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT_NUMBERS", schema = "public")
public class ContactsNumbers {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONTACT_ID")
    private Long contactId;
    @Column(name = "CONTACT_NO")
    private String contactNo;

    @Column(name = "MOBILE_VERIFIED")
    private String mobileVerified;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PER_PERSON_ID")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private People peopleTable;

    @Column(name = "PREFERRED")
    private String preferred;

    public void setContactId(Long contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }

    public Long getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    public String getMobileVerified() {
        return mobileVerified;
    }

    public void setMobileVerified(String mobileVerified) {
        this.mobileVerified = mobileVerified;
    }

    public String getPreferred() {
        return preferred;
    }

    public void setPreferred(String preferred) {
        this.preferred = preferred;
    }

   public People getPeopleTable() {
        return peopleTable;
    }

    public void setPeopleTable(People peopleTable) {
        this.peopleTable = peopleTable;
    }
```

I am trying to implement bi directional mappings between all the entities.

Comment: There is a very good document from baeldung that you can find here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion . it describes pretty good how to use ``@JsonBackReference``and ``@JsonManagedReference`` and the consequences of using one or another.

Comment: @BigZed I got the results for the users table but when I use the spring data jpa for the members I am unable to get the results, is there some hacky way?

Comment: Are there any messages that your terminal shows?

Comment: No, I am not getting any messages

Comment: Hi, I got it using JsonIdentifyInfo, thanks for the help!